# How to fix LimitExceeded issue in AWS with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

When I run a terraform apply, got this error:

```
running "...terraform apply" in ".../aws-config": exit status 1
module.aws_config_role.aws_iam_policy.default: Modifying... [id=arn:aws:iam::10391031030:policy/my-aws-config-role]

Error: Error updating IAM policy arn:aws:iam::10391031030:policy/my-aws-config-role: LimitExceeded: Cannot exceed quota for PolicySize: 6144
    status code: 409, request id: 313b0l20-a29d-0121-la32-01210d0103c01
```

In fact this task will update the IAM policy and add many new items, knows from terraform plan:

```
~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.aws_config_role.aws_iam_policy.default will be updated in-place
~ resource "aws_iam_policy" "default" {
        arn    = "arn:aws:iam::10391031030:policy/my-aws-config-role"
        id     = "arn:aws:iam::10391031030:policy/my-aws-config-role"
        name   = "my-aws-config-role"
        path   = "/"
      ~ policy = jsonencode(
          ~ {
              ~ Statement = [
                  ~ {
                      ~ Action   = [
                            "..." // old
                            "..." // old
                            "..." // old
                          + "..." // new
                          + "..." // new
                          + "..." // new
                          + "..." // new
                          + "..." // new
                          ...

 Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

After an aws provider version upgrade, got this change. How to avoid it? Ignore this task or is it possible to extend AWS' plicy size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The limit of `6144` characters for a managed policy is from AWS, not TF. So you have to fix/workaround it from AWS perspective, not TF.

You can follow **official AWS recommendation**s:

- [How can I increase the default managed policies or character size limit for an IAM role or user?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-increase-policy-size/)